# How to display pagination on View of action Index?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc

I work on asp.net core 5 vs 2019 i face issue I can't display Pagination of view action `Index` of controller `Cinemas` .

what I try is

1- create custom view model for `Cinemas` as below :

```
public class CinmaPageViewModel
        {
            public IEnumerable<CinimaViewModels> Cinmas { get; set; }
    
            public Pager Pager { get; set; }
        }
public class CinimaViewModels
    {
        public string Logo { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }

public class Pager
    {
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }

        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }
    }
```

2-create service and implementation class inheritance

```
public interface ICinemasService:IEntityBaseRepository<Cinema>
    {
        IQueryable<CinimaViewModels>GetAllCinimas();
    }



public class CinemasService:EntityBaseRepository<Cinema>, ICinemasService
    {
        private readonly AppDbContext _context;
        public CinemasService(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
public CinemasService(AppDbContext context) : base(context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

    public  IQueryable<CinimaViewModels> GetAllCinimas()
    {
        
        var response = _context.Cinemas.Select(x => new CinimaViewModels() { Logo = x.Logo, Name = x.Name,Description=x.Description });
        return response;

     
    }
```

3- on controller I return custom model view `CinmaPageViewModel`

```
[AllowAnonymous]
        public  IActionResult Index(int pageNumber = 1)
        {
            var allCinemas =  _service.GetAllCinimas();
            var result = _pageHelper.GetPage(allCinemas.AsQueryable(), pageNumber);

            var cinimas = new CinmaPageViewModel
            {
                Cinmas = result.Items,
                Pager = result.Pager
            };
 
            return View(cinimas);
        }
```

4-I create view `Index` as `Index.cshtml` for action `Index`  as below

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">

            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="text-center">
                        <th>logo</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Description</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    @foreach (var item in Model.Cinmas)
                    {
        <tr>
            <td class="align-middle">
                <img class="rounded-circle" src="@item.Logo" alt="@item.Name" style="max-width: 150px" />
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td class="align-middle">
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
            </td>

        </tr>}
                </tbody>

            </table>

        </div>
    </div>
```

How to display pagination on `index.cshtml` view for action `Index`
controller name `Cinemas`

Answer (score 1):

There are many methods to achieve pagination, Here I will show a simple demo about how to display pagination, Hope it can give you some help.

First add two properties in `Pager` model:

```
public class Pager
    {
        public int NumberOfPages { get; set; }

        public int CurrentPage { get; set; }

        public int TotalRecords { get; set; }

        public bool HasPreviousPage { get; set; }
        public bool HasNextPage { get; set; }
    }
```

In your code, there are some methods you don't provide. From the name of
`_service.GetAllCinimas();` , I think this method is to get all `Cinimas`. Then I write my own `GetPage()` method:

```
static CinmaPageViewModel GetPage(List<CinimaViewModels> model,int currentpage)
        {
            var totalrecode = model.Count();

            //I set each page can show 3 recods;
            var pagesize = 3;

            //Get cinimals
            var result = model.Skip(pagesize*(currentpage-1)).Take(pagesize);

            var TotalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling(totalrecode / (double)pagesize);

            Pager page = new Pager();
            page.CurrentPage = currentpage;
            page.TotalRecords = totalrecode;
            page.NumberOfPages = TotalPages;
            page.HasPreviousPage = (currentpage > 1);
            page.HasNextPage = (currentpage < TotalPages);

            CinmaPageViewModel resultmodel = new CinmaPageViewModel()
            {
                Cinmas = result.ToList(),
                Pager = page
            };

            return resultmodel;
        }
```

Action

```
public IActionResult Show(int pageNumber = 1)
        {
            var cinimalsAll = _service.GetAllCinimas();
            var result =  GetPage(cinimalsAll,pageNumber)
            return View(result);
        }
```

View

```
@model CinmaPageViewModel 

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8 offset-md-2">

        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <th>logo</th>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach (var item in Model.Cinmas)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            <img class="rounded-circle" src="@item.Logo" alt="@item.Name" style="max-width: 150px" />
                            
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
                        </td>
                        <td class="align-middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                        </td>

                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
            
        </table>

        @{
            var prevDisabled = !Model.Pager.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
            var nextDisabled = !Model.Pager.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
        }

        <a asp-action="Show"
           asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.Pager.CurrentPage -1 )"
           class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">
            Previous
        </a>

        @Model.Pager.CurrentPage/@Model.Pager.NumberOfPages

        <a asp-action="Show"
           asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1)"
           class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">
            Next
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

Demo

[image]

**Update:**

```
@{
                var prevDisabled = !Model.Pager.HasPreviousPage ? "disabled" : "";
                var nextDisabled = !Model.Pager.HasNextPage ? "disabled" : "";
            }

            <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
              <ul class="pagination justify-content-center">
                <li class="page-item disabled">
                    <a asp-action="Show" asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.Pager.CurrentPage -1 )" class="btn btn-default @prevDisabled">Previous</a>
                </li>
                    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Pager.NumberOfPages; i++)
                    {
                        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" asp-action="Show" asp-route-pageNumber="@(i+1)">@(i+1)</a></li>                
                    }
                <li class="page-item">
                  <a  asp-action="Show" asp-route-pageNumber="@(Model.Pager.CurrentPage + 1)" class="btn btn-default @nextDisabled">Next</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
```

demo:[image]

Comment: can you please tell me how to add page as 1-2-3-4 with previous and next buttons so remaining to display pag it self from 1 ,2,34 and accept click

Comment: @ahmed barbary, Please check the update.

Comment: this is good but can i custom my csharp code to use  generics so can use it with multiple classes and models

Comment: Do you mean you want to use this Pagination with different models? Actually it is just related to Pager model, Of course you can pass different model to `GetPage()`.

Comment: but return is fixed as CinmaPageViewModel

Comment: Sorry, I haven't met this issue before, You can create another question about this issue in stackoverflow.

Comment: i marked as answer and thanks much for support relly thanks you

Comment: marked as answer not show for me